# Conversion Failed when converting the varchar value '--' to date type INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report built from temp tables which im putting into an SSRS report. My report runs fine until I try and run it from the SSRS report.

the error im getting is

> Conversion Failed when converting the varchar value '--' to date type INT

I have other temp tables on this reports which run fine, there is only 1 extra condition in each mini SQL.

```
------TOTAL DATA ALLOCATED X0------

create table #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS
(
 [AGENT] varchar(32)
,[Allocated x1] int
)

insert into #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS
([AGENT],[Allocated x1])

Select ui.username [AGENT], count(DISTINCT(ah.accountid)) as [Allocated x1]
From [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
INNER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCELECMPAN] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = AH.ACCOUNTID
--INNER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = AH.ACCOUNTID
Where ah.source = 'Scar'
and ah.timesout = 1
and ah.createdate >= @startdate AND ah.createdate <= @enddate
and ui.username <> 'Loren Portwood'
group by ui.username
order by 1

------Quoted Elec------

create table #QUOTEDELECSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[QUOTED ELEC] int
)

insert into #QUOTEDELECSS1
([AGENT],[QUOTED ELEC])


Select [AGENT], Count(distinct(id)) as Count
from
(
SELECT DiSTINCT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.ACCOUNTID Order by E.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, E.ACCOUNTID AS ID, ui.username [AGENT], AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCELEC] E ON E.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION IN ('Renewal Quote - Elec: Confirm MPAN','Renewal Quote - Elec and Gas: Confirm MPAN and MPR')
AND A.ACCOUNTID NOT IN
(
SELECT A.ACCOUNTID
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCELECMPAN] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Elec: Confirm Price'
)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EM.MPANBOTTOM Order by EM.MPANBOTTOM) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, EM.DCLACCELECMPANID AS ID, ui.username [AGENT],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCELECMPAN] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Elec: Confirm Price'
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [AGENT]

------Quoted Gas------


create table #QUOTEDGASSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[QUOTED_GAS] int
)

insert into #QUOTEDGASSS1
([AGENT],[QUOTED_GAS])


Select [AGENT], Count(distinct(id)) as Count
from
(
SELECT DiSTINCT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.ACCOUNTID Order by E.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, E.ACCOUNTID AS ID, ui.username [AGENT], AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCgas] E ON E.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION IN ('Renewal Quote - Gas: Confirm MPR','Renewal Quote - Elec and Gas: Confirm MPAN and MPR')
AND A.ACCOUNTID NOT IN
(
SELECT A.ACCOUNTID
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCgasmpr] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Gas: Confirm Price'
)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EM.MPRSERIAL Order by EM.MPRSERIAL) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, EM.MPRSERIAL AS ID, ui.username [AGENT],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCgasmpr] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Gas: Confirm Price'
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [AGENT]


------GOOD ELEC------


create table #GOODELECSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[GOOD_ELEC] int
)

insert into #GOODELECSS1
([AGENT],[GOOD_ELEC])

Select [USERNAME], Count(DCLACCELECMPANID) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY em.MPANBOTTOM Order by em.MPANBOTTOM) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, EM.DCLACCELECMPANID, ui.username as [USERNAME], a.account, em.MPANBOTTOM,AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCELECMPAN] EM ON EM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Elec: Confirm Price'
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------GOOD GAS------


create table #GOODGASSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[GOOD_GAS] int
)

insert into #GOODGASSS1
([AGENT],[GOOD_GAS])

Select [USERNAME], Count(DCLACCGASMPRID) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GM.MPRSERIAL Order by GM.MPRSERIAL) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, GM.DCLACCGASMPRID, ui.username as [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
FROM ACCOUNT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSDBA.HISTORY H ON H.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sysdba].[DCLACCGASMPR] GM ON GM.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
WHERE LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and A.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and A.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
AND H.DESCRIPTION = 'Renewal Quote - Gas: Confirm Price'
) X where X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]


------LOA SUBMITTED ELEC------


create table #LOAELECSUBSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[LOA_SUBE] int
)

insert into #LOAELECSUBSS1
([AGENT],[LOA_SUBE])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID,  UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME], a.account,AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
from SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelec g
inner join [sysdba].[HISTORY] h on h.accountid = g.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[account] a on a.accountid = g.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
--where quotestage = 'LOA Submitted'
where h.description in ('LOA - Elec: LOA Submitted')
and a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
and ah.source = 'Scar'
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------LOA SUBMITTED GAS------


create table #LOAGASSUBSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[LOA_SUBG] int
)

insert into #LOAGASSUBSS1
([AGENT],[LOA_SUBG])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID,  UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], h.createdate [Quotedate],Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
from SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccgas g
inner join [sysdba].[HISTORY] h on h.accountid = g.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[account] a on a.accountid = g.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
--where quotestage = 'LOA Submitted'
where h.description in ('LOA - Gas: LOA Submitted')
and a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and Ah.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and Ah.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
and ah.source = 'Scar'
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------AWAITING CED ELEC------


create table #AWAITCEDELECSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[AWCED_ELEC] int
)

insert into #AWAITCEDELECSS1
([AGENT],[AWCED_ELEC])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID, UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], e.quotestagedate [Await_Date], Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
From SLXLive.sysdba.Account a
Inner Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelec e on a.accountid = e.accountid
Left Outer Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelecmpan m on e.accountid = m.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
Where a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and AH.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and AH.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (e.quotestagedate >Ah.CREATEDATE)
and ah.timesout = 0
and Quotestage = 'Awaiting CED' and m.signed_date is null
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------AWAITING CED GAS------


create table #AWAITCEDGASSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[AWCED_GAS] int
)

insert into #AWAITCEDGASSS1
([AGENT],[AWCED_GAS])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID, UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], e.quotestagedate [Await_Date], Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
From SLXLive.sysdba.Account a
Inner Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccgas e on a.accountid = e.accountid
Left Outer Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccgasmpr m on e.accountid = m.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
Where a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
and AH.CREATEDATE >= @startdate and AH.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (e.quotestagedate >Ah.CREATEDATE)
and Quotestage = 'Awaiting CED' and m.signed_date is null
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------SIGNED ELEC------

create table #ELECSIGNEDSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[SIGNED_ELEC] int
)

insert into #ELECSIGNEDSS1
([AGENT],[SIGNED_ELEC])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID, UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], m.signed_date [Signed_Date], Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
From SLXLive.sysdba.Account a
Inner Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelec e on a.accountid = e.accountid
Left Outer Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelecmpan m on e.accountid = m.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
Where a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
AND AH.CREATEDATE >= @Startdate and AH.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (m.signed_date >Ah.CREATEDATE)
and m.signed_date is not null
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]

------SIGNED GAS------

create table #GASSIGNEDSS1
(
     [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[SIGNED_GAS] int
)

insert into #GASSIGNEDSS1
([AGENT],[SIGNED_GAS])

Select [USERNAME], Count(accountid) as Count
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNTID Order by A.ACCOUNTID) ROWNUM,
CASE WHEN A.LEADSOURCEID = 'L6UJ9A00009H' THEN 'Scarlet Sheep'
     Else A.LEADSOURCEID END AS Leadsource, A.ACCOUNTID, UI.USERNAME AS [USERNAME],AH.TIMESOUT [Timesout], m.signed_date [Signed_Date], Ah.CREATEDATE [allocdate]
From SLXLive.sysdba.Account a
Inner Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccelec e on a.accountid = e.accountid
Left Outer Join SLXLive.sysdba.dclaccgasmpr m on e.accountid = m.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah on a.accountid = ah.accountid
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
Where a.leadsourceid = 'L6UJ9A00009H'
AND AH.CREATEDATE >= @Startdate and AH.CREATEDATE <= @enddate
AND (m.signed_date >Ah.CREATEDATE)
and m.signed_date is not null
) X WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1 AND X.timesout = 1
Group by [USERNAME]





--------------------------------------------------
------------Master Table--------------------------
--------------------------------------------------

create table #SCARLETTRESULTS1
(
    [AGENT] varchar(32)
    ,[Allocated x1] int
    ,[QUOTED ELEC] int
    ,[QUOTED_GAS] int
    ,[GOOD_ELEC] int
    ,[GOOD_GAS] int
    ,[LOA_SUBE] int
    ,[LOA_SUBG] int
    ,[AWCED_ELEC] int
    ,[AWCED_GAS] int
    ,[SIGNED_ELEC] int
    ,[SIGNED_GAS] int
)

insert into #SCARLETTRESULTS1
        ([AGENT],[Allocated x1],[QUOTED ELEC],[QUOTED_GAS],[GOOD_ELEC],[GOOD_GAS],[LOA_SUBE],[LOA_SUBG],[AWCED_ELEC],[AWCED_GAS],[SIGNED_ELEC],[SIGNED_GAS])

SELECT #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT],  #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[Allocated x1], #QUOTEDELECSS1.[QUOTED ELEC], #QUOTEDGASSS1.[QUOTED_GAS], #GOODELECSS1.[GOOD_ELEC], #GOODGASSS1.[GOOD_GAS], #LOAELECSUBSS1.[LOA_SUBE],
        #LOAGASSUBSS1.[LOA_SUBG], #AWAITCEDELECSS1.[AWCED_ELEC], #AWAITCEDGASSS1.[AWCED_GAS], #ELECSIGNEDSS1.[SIGNED_ELEC], #GASSIGNEDSS1.[SIGNED_GAS]
FROM #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS
        LEFT JOIN #QUOTEDELECSS1   ON #QUOTEDELECSS1.[AGENT]   = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #QUOTEDGASSS1    ON #QUOTEDGASSS1.[AGENT]    = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #GOODELECSS1     ON #GOODELECSS1.[AGENT]     = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #GOODGASSS1      ON #GOODGASSS1.[AGENT]      = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #LOAELECSUBSS1   ON #LOAELECSUBSS1.[AGENT]   = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #LOAGASSUBSS1    ON #LOAGASSUBSS1.[AGENT]    = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #AWAITCEDELECSS1 ON #AWAITCEDELECSS1.[AGENT] = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #AWAITCEDGASSS1  ON #AWAITCEDGASSS1.[AGENT]  = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #ELECSIGNEDSS1   ON #ELECSIGNEDSS1.[AGENT]   = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]
        LEFT JOIN #GASSIGNEDSS1    ON #GASSIGNEDSS1.[AGENT]    = #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.[AGENT]


--DROP TABLE #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS
--DROP TABLE #QUOTEDELECSS1
--DROP TABLE #QUOTEDGASSS1
--DROP TABLE #GOODELECSS1
--DROP TABLE #GOODGASSS1
--DROP TABLE #LOAELECSUBSS1
--DROP TABLE #LOAGASSUBSS1
--DROP TABLE #AWAITCEDELECSS1
--DROP TABLE #AWAITCEDGASSS1
--DROP TABLE #ELECSIGNEDSS1
--DROP TABLE #GASSIGNEDSS1
--DROP TABLE #SCARLETTRESULTS1

select isnull([AGENT],0) AS [AGENT], isnull([Allocated x1],0) AS [Allocated x1], isnull([QUOTED ELEC],0) AS [QUOTED ELEC], isnull([QUOTED_GAS],0) AS [QUOTED_GAS], isnull([GOOD_ELEC],0) AS [GOOD_ELEC]
, isnull([GOOD_GAS],0) AS [GOOD_GAS], isnull([LOA_SUBE],0) AS [LOA_SUBE], isnull([LOA_SUBG],0) AS [LOA_SUBG], isnull([AWCED_ELEC],0) AS [AWCED_ELEC], isnull([AWCED_GAS],0) AS [AWCED_GAS]
, isnull([SIGNED_ELEC],0) AS [SIGNED_ELEC], isnull([SIGNED_GAS],0) AS [SIGNED_GAS]
from #SCARLETTRESULTS1
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction cheers

Comment: Sure looks like SQL Server to me, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Whoa..dude that's a lot of code. Do you have any idea where you think the problem is? Could you maybe narrow it down a little bit, or break things up into more digestable chunks?

Comment: The way management want the report showing the proc is fairly chunky.

Comment: Error info contains line number, please provide it.

Comment: the only diiferenrce that I have changed since it stop working is added in    
    AND (h.createdate>Ah.CREATEDATE)
in each section

Comment: Ivan the error is on the report builder and has no error number at all, this all works fine in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have table #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS.  For any character fields you want to cast as numbers, use two columns.  The first will be a varchar column which you will use to receive the data from whereever.  The other will be integer, float, whatever you need.  Then do this:

```
update #DATAIMPORTEDX1SS
set theNumericField = cast(theVarcharField as integer)
where isNumeric(theVarcharField) = 1
```

Use theNumericField in your report.

Comment: This Code sorted out my report but has now failed and I cannot get it working. please can you explain the 2 columns?